# Is there a list of vocabulary that 5 or 6 year old children (native speakers of English) know/understand?

Tags: vocabulary

According to https://www.superduperinc.com/handouts/pdf/149_VocabularyDevelopment.pdf

> The 6-year-old child typically has a 2,600 word expressive vocabulary
>   (words he or she says), and a receptive vocabulary (words he or she
>   understands) of 20,000–24,000 words.

I am looking for such 2,600 (or 20,000-24,000) word list.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I would imagine there is such a list to gage a child's reading ability, which would be tricky as many six-year-olds still cannot read. As for the speaking... if you're teaching English to young children, then aim for the same sort of vocabulary that you expect any child to know, regardless of their mother tongue.

Comment: [*See Table 2 for a list of word meanings recommended for attention, explanation, or instruction for children ages 3 to 5 years.*](http://www.theroadmap.ualberta.ca/vocabularies)

Comment: Core Vocabulary https://www.gadoe.org/Curriculum-Instruction-and-Assessment/Special-Education-Services/Documents/IDEAS%202014%20Handouts/Comm.Peeled.Cored%20ppt.pdf

Answer (score 4):

I think you've misunderstood what the passage is saying. Different children will know and use different words; the passage merely says that, for any given child of that age, the size of that child's expressive vocabulary will typically be 2,600 words.

Furthermore, while I don't know what research underlies its claim, I think it's unlikely to have involved obtaining a complete list of even a single child's expressive vocabulary; rather, it would more likely have used statistical techniques to estimate the number of distinct words that the child ever uses by examining the frequencies of words in some corpus of the child's speech.